# Используя возможности MPI, реализовать параллельный алгоритм умножения матриц

Tags: матрицы, c++, mpi

Здравствуйте, у меня такая задача. Используя возможности MPI, реализовать параллельный алгоритм умножения матриц. Пишет ошибку :

```
ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _MPI_Init в функции "void __cdecl MultiplyMatrix(float *,float *,float *,int)" (?MultiplyMatrix@@YAXPAM00H@Z)
```

код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <mpi.h>
#define N 100

using namespace std;
 float *CreateMatrix( int n)
    {
        float *matr = new float [n*n];
        return matr;

    }
 void FillMatrix(float *matrix, int n)
 {

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)

        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)

            *(matrix+i*n+j) = rand()%10;
 }
 void MultiplyMatrix(float *mA,float *mB, float *mC,int n)
 {
     int rank;
int size;

     int argc;
     char **argv;
     MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

     MPI_Bcast(&n,1,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
    int i;
    int j;
    float matrix;
    //MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
 {if (rank!=0) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            float s = 0;
            for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
            {
                s +=*(mA+i*n+k) * *(mB+k*n+j);
                //s=s%10;
            }

            *(mC+i*n+j) = s;
        }
 }
 }
  //  MPI_Reduce(&mC+i*n+j,&matrix,1,MPI_FLOAT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     MPI_Finalize();    
 }

 void PrintMatrix(float *matrix,char *name, int n)
 {  
     cout<<"Matrix\t";
     cout<<name;
     cout<<"\n";
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout<<*(matrix+i*n+j) <<' ';

        }
        cout<<endl;   
    }
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int SIZE = 20;

    int n;

float *mA;
float *mB;
float *mC;
double t1,t2,t3,t4;
double total_1, total_2,total_3;
printf("\n ===SIZE=========LAB1============MPI=====\n"); 
for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
float start_time;
float total_time;
float search_time;
float end_time;

for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
{
    mA = CreateMatrix(SIZE);
    mB = CreateMatrix(SIZE);
    mC = CreateMatrix(SIZE);
    FillMatrix(mA, SIZE);
    FillMatrix(mB, SIZE);
    total_1 = total_2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        t1 = clock();
        MultiplyMatrix(mA,mB,mC,SIZE);
        t2 = clock();
        MultiplyMatrix(mA,mB,mC,SIZE);
        t3 = clock();
        total_1 += (t2-t1);
        total_2 += (t3-t2);
    }
    printf("\n    %dx%d\t%.4lf  \t%.4lf",SIZE,SIZE,total_1/N,total_2/N);
    SIZE += 30;
    delete mA;
    delete mB;
    delete mC;
}
printf("\n\n =================================\n"); 
printf("\n\n");

    getch();
//MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    return 0;

}
```

Помогите,пожалуйста.В чем ошибка?

Comment: У Вас библиотека не подключается.

Для linux посмотрите опции компилятора [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312719/how-to-compile-mpi-with-gcc), а для винды (только по `getch` догадался) [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795548/how-to-compile-and-execute-c-program-with-both-mpi-and-openmp-on-windows) (вообще-то указывайте в вопросе ОС, компилятор и т.п.).

Comment: @avp: судя по `#include <conio.h>`, это не винда, а даже DOS. Visual Studio С++, начиная с где-то 2010-й, уже вполне себе поддерживают стандарты.

Comment: Пишет вот такую ошибку 1
>lab_5.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _MPI_Init в функции "void __cdecl MultiplyMatrix(float *,float *,float *,int)" (?MultiplyMatrix@@YAXPAM00H@Z)

Answer (score 1):

Прочтите документацию к вашей реализации MPI. В Linux всё компилируется командой mpicc (вместо cc) или mpicxx (для c++). В Винде-ДОСе так тоже можно, но не зная что и как у вас поставлено ответить однозначно невозможно.